# I want to read from such folder if you put specific url in addess bar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i tried thie:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.example.com$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^image/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobile_version/
RewriteRule (.*) /mobile_version/$1 [L]
```

but it did not work well

I want if user put in address bas: m.example.com read from mobile_version also if put 
m.example.com/image/125 read from mobile_version.

what's the wrong in above

Answer (score 1):

this should do a tirck

```
$splitURL = explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if($splitURL[0]=="m"){
 include mobile version ;   
}else {
 //include desktop version  
 }
```

EDIT:

modify .htaccess file

**ERRORDOCUMENT 404 /redirect.php**

now create a redirect.php file and embedd the above php code

Comment: i need it in htaccess?